# Python / Google API - The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces

Tags: python, google-drive-api

everyone.
I tried different approaches A LOT, and here:
[How to read Drive Photos using Drive Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482119/how-to-read-drive-photos-using-drive-rest-api)
found a solution.
But neverless:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly'

store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials1.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

driveService = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# driveService = apiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http = httpAuth) # Выбираем работу с Google Drive и 3 версию API
print(driveService)
page_token = None
while True:
    print("1")
    response = driveService.files().list(q="mimeType='images/jpeg'",
                                          spaces='photos',
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print(file.get('link'))
        photos1.append(file.get('name'))
        photos2.append(file.get('id'))
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        print("2")
        break
```

Gives the error above

Update:

```
response = driveService.files().list(
        spaces='photos').execute()
```

Returns nothing, despite my Drive sure has photos.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't understand about your goal. So can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I want to get list of all my photos in gdrive, but I cant as i dont have an access to it. I tried to add special url to scope, but it didn't work

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you can see the Google Photo folder in your Google Drive, you can retrieve them using Drive API. If you want to retrieve the items of Google Photo which cannot be seen in your Google Drive, you can retrieve them using Photo API. Can I ask you about which situation is your current situation?

Comment: Big thank you for answer. In my Google Drive I don't see any Google Photo folder, so, I assume, that I need to get photo directly from Drive main root. For example, I tried to follow https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files, but files.list() returns everything but images. Next step was the try, that is here. Have no thoughts...TY

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, in your case, I think that the files can be seen at [Google Photo](https://photos.google.com/). Can you confirm this? If you can see them at there and if you want to retrieve them using a script, it is required to retrieve the list using Google Photo API.

Comment: No, in Google Photos I see absolutely different photos. Actually, I have my Google Photos API configured and I have access to it, but my main task is to create a Telegram bot, who sends images to users. I can send a link to user, but as this link "unshared", user sees just a plain link text with no "preview" (if you understand me). When I send "sharable" link, it works just as fine, but I can't do that from script :(. There is an API for shared albums, but it changes nothing as I understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize I misunderstood your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question and comments I understood that you want to [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) all image files from Photos in your Drive. Starting in [July 2019](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/), pictures uploaded to Photos won't automatically show on Drive and vice versa. You can read more about that change [here](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089).

Based on your scenario, I strongly recommend uploading your pictures to Drive and [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) the properties `webContentLink` or `webViewLink` (depending if you want users to download the image or just view it) from the API. Please, ask me any question for further help.